# How to perform aggregation without considering certain value from a column and calculating mathematical metrics using Python

Tags: python, database, aggregate

| Call_ID | UUID | Intent_Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | Loan_BankAccount |
| A | 234 | StopCheque |
| A | 789 | Request_Agent_phone_number |
| B | 900 | Loan_BankAccount |
| B | 787 | Request_Agent_BankAcc |

I have the above table where "**Call_ID**" means a call that has been made, "**UUID**" is a unique key for a turn in the same call (Suppose **Call A** can have multiple turns such as **123, 234, 789**(here)) and "Intent_Product" refers to the description of the query.

**The expected output is :**

| Intent_Product | Resolved_Count | Contained_Turns | Contained_Calls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Loan_BankAcc | 2 | 1 | 0.5 |
| Stop_Cheque | 1 | 0 | 0 |

**Conditions :**

1. **Resolution_Count :-** Count of the total number of queries that has been resolved ( Here, for example "Loan_BankAccount" =2 , "StopCheque" = 1) (where "Intent_Product" like "Request_Agent" , have to ignored as those are not resolved)
2. **Contained_Turns :-** Count the total number of queries that has been contained, but ignore those queries which has "Intent_Product" like "Request_Agent" as the successor. ( example :- here Containment count for "Loan_BankAccount" = 1 and Stop_Cheque" = 0 )
3. **Contained_Calls :-** This would be equal to **(Contained_Turns)/(Resolution_Count)**